# Capybara exclude a div in search?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

Is there a way to tell Capybara to ignore a div when searching a page.

Something like

```
page.assert_no_selector('a', :unless => '.an-excused-class a')
```

Alternatively, is there a way in a specific step to tell Capybara to not count hidden elements. I've seen some ways to do that globally, but that's not what I want.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no way in Capybaras default assertions to tell it to ignore some elements that match a selector.
2. By default Capybara won't find hidden elements, if you have overridden that by changing the Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements option you can specify the :visible option in the assertion

   page.assert_no_selector('a', visible: true)

the visible option can take a number of values:

- true or :visible  => only find visible elements
- false or :all   => find elements no matter their visibility
- :hidden => only find non-visible elements

Answer (score 0):

If there are two divs that are the same, but one is hidden, capybara will automatically only look for the visible div.

However if you have the opposite value in the global settings for capybara using the option:

```
:visible
```

ie.

```
page.should have_css("ol li", :visible => true)
```

Will force it to only check for the visible div.

However if using the visibility option is a complete no go, there could be other ways to tell if its there.

Using a count method could tell you if the correct number of the named div are on the page:

```
page.should have_css("ol li", :count => 2)
```

Or if you know the div is always going to be, say the third:

```
page.all("ol li")[3]
```

Finally, if those divs are enclosed in separate blocks of HTML that are labelled differently - you can look within the HTML to find them by chaining with capybara:

```
page.find('#foo').find('.bar')
```

A good source of this information :

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method